# Change CTRL-X, -C, and -V hotkeys in Windows to different keys

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I use my mouse left-handed, which makes the default Cut/Copy/Paste hotkeys in Windows really akward to use. Is there any way I can change these - say to something like Control-m, comma, and period? That way, I could mouse with my left hand and use my right for the hotkey functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use AutoHotkey to assign the same function to another combo. The benefit is that the old ones will still work as well so if someone else uses your machine it wont throw them off:

```
^m::^x
^,::^c
^.::^v
```

Comment: I spent some time for how to do this, so I'll add it here hoping it helps someone... I also remapped the Windows Key + R and used the following:

#r::run, explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}

Comment: for those who also don't know what AutoHotkey is: It is a 3rd party application and its homepage is: https://autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 9):

You might be interested to learn that there are [alternative hotkeys](https://superuser.com/questions/428350/why-does-windows-7-sometimes-copy-to-clipboard-after-i-press-the-delete-key/428356#428356) available:

- Copy: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>
- Cut: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- Paste: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>

These hotkeys seem to have been derived from the [IBM CUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access). However, I don't know if they were specifically chosen for left-handed users.

Comment: And for the equiv of `Ctrl+A` you have `Shift+PgDown` though you'll have to hold it.

Comment: Hmm - those hotkeys seem to work (I had no idea), though they're not really what I'm after, as they're awkward to reach with my right hand. Good to know, though!

Answer (score 0):

These are not **Windows**-specific, but since they are almost unknown and sometimes they are helpful, this is probably a good place to mention them. Note that you can only do a **rectangular** select.

In **DOS** (yes ... some folks still insist on running some oddball DOS program ...):

**Copy:** Alt + {space}, e, k (move cursor to select, press enter)

**Paste:** Alt + {space}, e, p

**Cut:** (not available)

**Select All:** (not available)

Often you can enable the Windows key set with QuickEditMode. But if there is some conflict, the Alt + {space} combinations will still work.

Answer (score -1):

If you use AutoHotkey application for Windows you should create file .ahk with content below

```
!z::^z    
!x::^x    
!c::^c    
!v::^v
```

Than double click on it file and it's work

Comment: How does this add anything versus the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/166271)?