# Replace the Ctrl+C function with another key in Windows

Tags: windows

Is there a way to press a key on the keyboard (for example <kbd>C</kbd>) for copying text? I don't want to remap <kbd>C</kbd>to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, basically if <kbd>C</kbd> is pressed a copy should happen.

Comment: And how do you type a "c" now?

Comment: it does not matter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) to change your keyboard shortcuts, without remapping them.

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/166270/change-ctrl-x-c-and-v-hotkeys-in-windows-to-different-keys) answer.

Comment: AutoHotKey uses remapping, i have checked it with visual studio debugging

Comment: @user2675751 You can have multiple key combinations for one task. For example you can have 3 buttons assigned to **copy**, so what is the problem?

Comment: thanks for your replay, problem is this: while debugging an application, there is a check for ctrl+c in keyword-preview-event i want to fool that!